# Trying to fill gaps with liquid nails?

Tags: technique

Basically I am making a wooden tick tack toe toilet paper holder. I'm wondering how to make my gaps look seamless before I paint. This is my first time ever attempting something on my own, (at 40 yrs old... Lol) I am hoping to just smooth in some liquid nails to make the cracks and uneven edges seamless... I will try include another Pic for reference of what I'm aiming for... (https://i.stack.imgur.com/q76Hz.jpg)[image]

Comment: Tried to post my attempt. I apologize and am thankful for any advice.          
  https://ibb.co/DRhy9cN

Comment: Hi Jen, welcome to StackExchange. You can certainly fill for a more seamless appearance when painting but Liquid Nails is not the right product for it. Have a poke around using the internal search here (it works very well) for filler with and without paint and you're sure to find some better options.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much!

Comment: Cool project! As @Graphus says, you want 'wood filler', not liquid nails.

Comment: Does the picture displayed inline in the question represent what you are aiming for? If so, I have to say your work doesn't appear to be of significantly worse quality. I think you're just very familiar with the flaws in your own project. Which I get -- it happens to all of us! Aim high, but don't be too hard on yourself. It's likely onlookers won't notice the gaps unless you point them out. Still, nothing wrong with aiming to improve!

Comment: FWIW: I kind of like the gaps... "rustic" is cool.